# make ie behave like a standards-compliant browser

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I'm looking for "the best" script that makes Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 behave like a standards-compliant browser, making it support CSS3, PNG transparency and other features.

It might be a jQuery plugin or some raw JavaScript with some CSS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Does [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) count?

And if it doesn't, I don't think there is any javascript library or jQuery plugin that does what you want. There might be the odd thing (e.g. [curvycorners.js](http://www.curvycorners.net/)) that may address the odd feature, but having a large number of these to cover a wide range of features would be horribly hacky and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I'll check it out and tell you ;)

Comment: This is actually the only way to make IE standards compliant. A bit of Javascript is not sufficient.

Comment: I got it but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for, I'm a web developer and I want to make my websites look the same for all my visitors, it's not just for me to get the page display well, so the plugin must be available for all my visitors, that's why it must be javescript or something like that. I found this but it seems it's for ver. 7 and below. http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think there is a silver bullet for what you are trying to do. If there was we'd all already be using it.

Comment: @Earlz: thanks for the idea but it seems only dealing with html5 and not javescript and css

Comment: @DanSingerman: did you take a look at the link I provided? code.google.com/p/ie7-js

Comment: I did. It seems to do a few things, but it seems far from feature complete